# How to display related subcategory through select DBGrid Main Category

Tags: delphi

I'm beginner at this field, so this question might be weird but please understand.

i have two different DBgrid, one is Main Category the other is Subcategory and detail information about Main. (e.g Item[0].ID -> Item[0].index[0],[1],...)

so my question is assume that i select Item[0].ID, then how to display related Subcategory and details?

it doesn't have to be a DBGrid, if it's necessary, you could use any other components.

I really ask for your wisdom

I use Delphi xe5 and interbase 2017, and I've tried divide every single items on Main Category. but that makes me made 88 different units and DBfiles. it's so messy

what i expected was choose one of Main category and show me related info, but what I actually see was so many different units.

Comment: You should look at the `MasterSource` and `MasterFields` properties of your subcategory dataset. The documentation covers these well; IIRC, there's even a tutorial in the Delphi help file (in the database programming section) on using master/detail tables.

Comment: See [Establishing Master-detail Relationships Using Parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Establishing_Master-detail_Relationships_Using_Parameters)

Comment: thanks a lot , I really appreciate you :)